# get further value for a selected value of a dropdown box using Jquery and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

How can I get further value for a selected value of a dropdown box using jQuery?
I tried this using

```
var value = $('#dropDownId').val();
```

and

```
var value = $('select#dropDownId option:selected').val();
```

but both returns an empty string.

Please define, If it is possible by using AJAX.

Comment: Both are correct ways for getting the currently selected value of a dropdown. A dropdown matching that selector does probably not exist in the DOM at the point at which the code is being executed, or its value is indeed an empty string.

Comment: yes quite possible, do some googling, you would find plenty of tuts about that.

Comment: i think you might be using `<asp:dropdownlist>`. is it?

Comment: There is literally nothing `ajax` related about this question. Please post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

using java script you can do this as follows

```
var elem = document.getElementById('dropDownId');

var selIndex = elem.selectedIndex;

var val = elem.options[selIndex].value;
```